# How to use CoreLocation with swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I've tried using CoreLocation with my Swift app, but without luck. I have the following incredibly simple code:

(I've linked the CoreLocation library.)

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self
```

On the last line I get the error "Expected declaration."

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following code `locationManager.delegate = self` is a statement. You need to execute it within one of the AppDelegate methods. For example:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    func application(application :UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:NSDictionary>) -> Bool {
       locationManager.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: that wont work I think. Cus' self refers back to the AppDelegate, which doesn't conform to CoreLocation

Comment: @Chris - true, but I am hoping the OP understand the basics of implementing protocols!

Comment: Thanks! Stupid mistake. It was a while ago I did iOS programming. (Btw, the delegate function is there in my code, I only the few relevant lines)