# Handling Location Permission in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I want to check user location services are Enable or not after user **Allow** or **Disallow** location permission, I checked in viewdidload method for permission, but it appears before user set permission, I wanted to run this code after user set Location permission(Allow or Don't Allow) from permission popup in device.
**Objective c**

-(void)viewDidLoad

```
if(status==kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        float latitude;
        float longitude;
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [self myLocation];
        latitude = coordinate.latitude;
        longitude = coordinate.longitude;
        status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];

    CLGeocoder*myGeocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];

    [myGeocoder
     reverseGeocodeLocation:location
     completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

         if (error == nil && placemarks.count > 0){

             CLPlacemark *placemark = placemarks[0];
             if ([placemark.locality isEqualToString:@"Mumbai"]) {
                 NSLog(@"Location is Mumbai");
             }
             else{
                 if (placemark.locality) {
                     alert=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"This app is not available @%@",placemark.locality] preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                     [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                 }
                 else{
                     alert=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"This app is not available at your location" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
                     [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
                 }
             }


         }
         else if (error == nil && placemarks.count == 0){
             NSLog(@"No results were returned.");
         }
         else if (error != nil) {
             NSLog(@"An error occurred = %@", error);
         }
     }];
}
else{

    alert=[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Location Permission" message:@"To re-enable, please go to Settings and turn on Location Service for this app." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *Retry=[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Retry" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
        exit(0);
    }];
    [alert addAction:Retry];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: I have swift code !!

Comment: Plzz suggest . . . If I can make any idea on basis of it.

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933593/handling-location-permissions-instantaneously-in-swift)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First include delegate:

> CLLocationManagerDelegate

Declaring property:

> @property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

In view did load add following:

```
if( _locationManager == nil )
    {
        _locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        _locationManager.delegate = self;
        _locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [_locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }

[self checkLocationAccess];
```

And the checkLocationAccess method:

```
- (void)checkLocationAccess {
    CLAuthorizationStatus status = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
    switch (status) {

    // custom methods after each case

        case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
            [self allowLocationAccess]; // custom method
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
            [self allowLocationAccess]; // custom method
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways:
            break;
        case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse:
            break;
    }
}
```

Observer method:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        NSLog(@"allowed"); // allowed
    }
    else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        NSLog(@"denied"); // denied
    } 
}
```

Comment: It prints kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined before I select permission.

Comment: It should go to kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined before you select permission because you've not selected (Allow or Not) yet.

Comment: Bro I want to print permission status when i click on permission allow or not . . . . . not before I set permission. . . . in short when I set permission then It should print the permission Status @shanezzar

Comment: Check the updated answer now, the above method show be called to detect authorization status change.

Comment: Hello @shanezzar, When I get phone call application sent to background and Delegate method stops working, so did you know how to get rid of it?? how to restart delegate method on application comes to foreground?

Comment: For this purpose I use nsnotificationcenter to detect that app has gone background or returned back from the background. You can use the same action/method on these observers too...